# Detect Win+Tab Task View

Tags: c, winapi, dwm

On Windows 10, you can press <kbd>Win+Tab</kbd> to get a "Task View" view of all your windows. I'm trying to check if this is active at any given time. I have tried using a Low Level Keyboard Hook with `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` but this only allows me to detect the keypress, not if the switcher is active. I've looked at the Windows DWM API and haven't found anything else either.

I have also tried using `EnumWindows()` and `EnumChildWindows(GetDesktopWindow(), ...)` and did not find any difference in the output between having the task view shown and hidden.

Is there any accurate method to detect if this is being shown?

Comment: There is no API for that particular purpose.  Why do you need this?  It sounds like a possible [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: Writing a gesture recognition program that sends a Win+Tab to open the task view with a gesture, but only if it's not open already.

Comment: You can detect it via `FindWindow` passing the special class name of the switcher.  Unfortunately, you can't use the usual method (Spy++) to learn the class name, because using Spy++ will close the switcher.  So instead do this: Make the gesture, instead of sending Win+Tab, do a `EnumWindows` writing the window list to a file.  Do the gesture with the switcher open, then look in the file to see what you found.  Once you know the class name for the switcher, you can skip `EnumWindows` and just do `FindWindow`.

Comment: Also note  "#32771 The class for the task switch window." in the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574(v=vs.85).aspx#system but I rather suspect that's for the older (Alt+Tab) switcher.  I don't know if the class for the new switcher is documented but you can find out yourself.

Comment: Been trying that, but the results are basically identical with the exception of some unnamed windows.

Comment: Use `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to check if these windows belong to explorer.exe which is the process responsible for the task switcher I believe. Use `GetClassName` to determine the class name.

Comment: I have noticed that `Shell_TrayWnd` is not a child of GetDesktopWindow() when task view is open. Will try using that as an indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that works very consistently with my version of Windows (1709 build 16299.125) and doesn't require the processor-heavy approach of a call to `EnumChildWindows`:

```
bool isTaskView() {
    //Get foreground window's name
    HWND fgWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
    TCHAR windowName[MAX_PATH] = L"";
    GetWindowText(fgWindow, windowName, MAX_PATH);
    //Compare with magic string name of Task View's window
    std::wstring nameStr(windowName);
    return nameStr == L"Task View";
}
```