# Detect show/hide Task View (Win+Tab)

Tags: winapi, dwm, windows-10-desktop

I'm developing a [Application Desktop Toolbar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/cc144177(v=vs.85).aspx) (next Toolbar). Toolbar receives [`ABN_FULLSCREENAPP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/bb787965(v=vs.85).aspx) notification when a fullscreen application window is opened or closed (e.g. through <kbd>F11</kbd>). A window is fullscreen when its client area occupies the entire screen. Toolbar should take themselves out of the topmost z-order so that they do not cover the fullscreen window. For this I use `SetWindowPos()` with flag `HWND_BOTTOM/HWND_TOPMOST`.

**Problem:** On Windows 10 when a fullscreen application window is opened (e.g. Explorer window through <kbd>F11</kbd>) Toolbar receives `ABN_FULLSCREENAPP` and send themselves to bottom z-order. Then, when <kbd>Win + Tab</kbd> is pressed, Task View appears. Task View occupies the entire working area of the screen - entire screen exclude the Taskbar area and the Toolbar area. But Toolbar remains under the full-screen window and Takbar appears on top, see image below. I want the Toolbar to also be on top of the full-screen window when TaskVew is open.

During the opening of Task View, Toolbar does not receive any messages. Apparently since Microsoft [stopped](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120912-00/?p=6623/) development of the ADT API, there is no special message for the Toolbars.

**Possible solutions:**
1) Use the solution from [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46653985/detect-wintab-task-view) by performing the function in the timer between the opening and closing of the full-screen window;
2) Use [`LowLevelKeyboardProc()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms644985(v=vs.85).aspx) with `SetWindowsHookEx()`.

Both solutions are not elegant. If you know other method of detecting the opening / closing TaskView please report. Undocumented methods are also useful.

[image: Windows 10 Task View behaviour]

Comment: The full screen window is still open while the TaskView is visible. The TaskView is simply on top of it. So why do you expect your toolbar to be notified? The TaskView is clearly taking your toolbar into account when filling the working area. The full screen window is simply covering your toolbar, as it should be. So what are you expecting your toolbar to do when TaskView is made visible while a full screen window is open? Do you want your toolbar to move on top of the full screen window? You could just call the other solution's `isTaskViewOpen()` in a timer while a full screen window is open.

Comment: Thanks. Added details to the question. Yes, i want the toolbar to move on top of the full-screen window when TaskView is open and vice versa.